# R Shiny updating UI server side

Tags: r, shiny

I have a large shiny app with many modules. Some of these modules have a `pickerInput` UI-element, which are filled with data on the server-side (using `updatePickerInput`), because they are too large. My problem is, that a lot of calculations are done **BEFORE** the `updatePickerInput` has a chance to fill the values, often with `NULL` values which cause some output elements to appear with error. Using `validate`/`need` or `req` in every output element seems not very efficient, producing a lot of boilerplate code. So I wanted to know if there is a way to tell the application to only run subsequent calculations if the `update` calls on the server are finished.

In the (very simplified) example below you can see, that the `updatePickerInput`-function is executed after the `renderText` (in the first run). What I would like to have is, that the update takes place before the first rendering.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyWidgets)

randText <- c(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T), NULL)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("test", "Choose me", choices = NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = T),
  textOutput("randText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updatePickerInput(session, "test", choices = randText, selected = randText[1:50])
  output$randText <- renderText({
    validate(need(!is.null(input$test), "MOOOOORE!"))
    Sys.sleep(3)
    paste0(input$test)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Doesn't `updatePickerInput` takes place before the first rendering? I think it is in your example. Can you move  both task in an `observeEvent`?

Comment: No, `updatePickerInput` initializes after `renderText`. What should be the event observed?

Comment: Why don't you use `req`, replace your `validate` with `req(input$test)` will work and no error message. it's very simple. I don't see the claim "seems not very efficient". Using other code, like another observer suggested above complicates the code.  You can do something like

```observeEvent(input$test, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    output$randText <- renderText({
      Sys.sleep(3)
      paste0(input$test)
    })
  })```

Isn't this more complex?

Comment: I don't know of any easy mechanism to force the `update` to evaluate before the `renderText`. Unfortunately, the `req`/`validate` pattern is what shiny offers you to determine if the `output` should be rendered or not. If `validate(need(!is.null(input$test), "MOOOOORE!"))` is too much boilerplate for you, you could wrap it in a function to have less to type

Comment: @starja validate/need has to be used in every output element, and my app has almost 50 different output elements. So yes, it is too much boilerplate code writing validate/need 50 times, whereas if I could tell shiny to not calculate before updating the ui is done I would need it maybe 5 times.